# Split by '/' till '[' appears

Tags: c#, regex

I want to split the following kind of string:

> Parent/Child/Value [4za] AX/BY

and get create a `String[]` out of it via:

```
String[] ArrayVar = Regex.Split(stringVar, "?");
```

which split the string by every `/` before first appearance of `[`.

So as result I would get

```
Array[0] => "Parent"
Array[1] => "Child"
Array[2] => "Value [4za] AX/BY"
```

strings could also have other formats like

> Parent/Value [4za] AX/BY
>
> Value [4za] AX/BY

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind (`(?<!...)`). The following regex means "`/` not preceded by opening bracket":

```
(?<!\[.*)/
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5b.*%29%2f&i=Parent%2fChild%2fValue+%5b4za%5d+AX%2fBY)

C# demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/85S3cK

Comment: FYI: If the string contains line breaks, it might be useful to pass a singleline ("dotall") option to the regex engine, `@"(?s)(?<!\[.*)/"` or `Regex.Split(stringVar, @"(?<!\[.*)/", RegexOptions.Singleline);`.

Comment: And if the engine doesn't support arbitrary-length lookbehinds?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, without arbitrary-length lookbehinds, a single regex statement would either be impossible or likely way too complex to be worth the cost in effort and readability over a solution like TheLethalCoder's answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yes, agree. But I got the OP's input sample as suggesting on-line input string.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: for such engines we may employ different approach: match all parts with a specific pattern ([`[^\/]*\[.*|[^\/]+`](https://regex101.com/r/zYGweM/1) in this particular case) and return an array of matches: `"Parent/Child/Value [4za] AX/BY".match(/[^\/]*\[.*|[^\/]+/g)`

Answer (score 33):

You could use normal string operations to do this. Just split the string on the first `[` then split that accordingly. Then just add the end part of the string onto the last element:

```
string inputstring = "Parent/Child/Value [4za] AX/BY";

int index = inputstring.IndexOf('[');

string[] parts = inputstring.Substring(0, index).Split('/');
parts[parts.Length - 1] += inputstring.Substring(index);
```

Comment: If the `Regex` isn't compiled then this method could in fact be faster.

Comment: Even if the regex is compiled, this is probably faster.

Comment: This is fine, but the one-liner is not worse and is readable enough.

Comment: The functionality of this is instantly recognizable of far more people than a regex. This could be simplified a little, but is still overall more readable, even if it takes a handful more lines of code.